# Grails: ConfigObject.plus() not available in integration test

Tags: unit-testing, testing, grails, missingmethodexception

I am testing a service which is using config attributes and concatenates it to a string, like that:

```
 GrailsConfig.config.test.directory + System.getProperty('file.separator')
 + <filename>
```

When running the test for the above method containing the above code I receive the following error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
groovy.util.ConfigObject.plus() is applicable for argument types:
(java.lang.String) values: [\]
```

Why is the plus operator not available in my integration (or unit) test?!

Any help appreciated

Jonas

Answer (score 1):

This is the error that you see when you haven't defined a config variable. You've probably defined the `test.directory` in another environment, but not the `test` environment.

In a unit test, you should be using mockConfig as Don's answer suggests, but in an integration test, you can use the grails configuration framework just as you would when running the app.

Answer (score 0):

I guess `GrailsConfig.config.test.directory` should return a String, but it's returning a `ConfigObject` instead (which doesn't overload the + operator). I've never tried using `GrailsConfig` in an integration test, so I don't know if this code is expected to work.

A better approach might be to mock the configuration values using [mockConfig](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/12/grails-goodness-mocking-configuration.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the issue... All String attributes must be in quotes when using `mockConfig` which is not the case in out config properties file.